# Any patterns to follow to share huge DB data over REST

Tags: java, database, stream

I have a situation where I need to share huge data (probably in billions) over REST. Any particular design pattern to follow. I read something about scrolls that are available in Elastic where we can initialize the scroll once and then use it to retrieve subsequent data in batches.

I have using MySQL database where all my data is stored and i need to share all the data over REST services. I am using Spring BOOT for REST.

I have thought of a way where I open a connection and starting getting the data and write in a blocking queue in a producer consumer pattern and then give back a handle (id) to client for subsequent calls to get next batch.

Is there a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: Question of curiosity: why REST (or even http) for this?

Comment: Maybe pagination is a buzz word here

Comment: @ernest_k data is encapsulated and data can only be accessed via REST

Comment: @SteveBenett pagination? how?

Comment: @M.J. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html
Idea is to get all data page for page and not all at once. Furthermore, if the download fails for a page it can be resumed at this point.

Comment: @M.J. Even in that case, I think (yes, it's an opinion) that using a different integration pattern will be far more productive and effectual for both parties. Think of using something like Kafka here, you would have a working solution with relatively far less work and fewer puzzles to solve (even if the data sending has to be triggered using an http call)